# How do I facilitate access to an Azure based SQL View for non-SQL users on Prem?

Tags: azure-sql-database, reporting

Afternoon

I'm hoping this one is simple and my general lack of Azure knowledge is the problem, but I need to present data from within a view to some non-SQL end users via some form of application / web view.

Is there a simple tool or function anyone is aware of in Azure that will allow this?  Something akin to a traditional SSRS front end where they can navigate to and run this simple report for example?

Thanks in advance for any direction you can provide.

Comment: Is this in Azure SQL DB, or SQL Server running in a virtual machine?

Comment: Azure SQL DB running in an Elastic Pool

Comment: Code it, use [excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-a-Microsoft-Azure-SQL-Database-Power-Query-9f621fd9-5f22-4c57-b247-eb0be8b7bac4), use [PowerBI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-power-bi-to-visualize-and-explore-azure-sql-databases/), or use [SSRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/sql-azure-connection-type-ssrs). What is the issue with any of these?

Comment: All excellent suggestions, however, I am unable to connect to the Azure DB in question directly from our Corporate network so i'm wholly reliant upon something cloud based with an option to push out data securely.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Power BI service and Power BI Mobile Apps to share reports with others as explained [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-share-unshare-dashboard/). Take a look [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-publish-to-web/) at the Publish to Web feature in Power BI.

[Here](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0019.htm) you can see how easy is to create a report from SQL Azure data on Power BI.

Hope this helps.

Comment: PowerBI involves too much end-user interaction sadly.  I'm aiming this at people who would, in an ideal world, get the data in excel via e-mail.   I'm currently wondering if Azure Automation may help?

Comment: You can do email subscriptions in Power BI: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-email-subscriptions-in-power-bi-stay-informed-when-it-matters/